# Javascript - Multidimension Monte Carlo Array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, montecarlo

I'm trying to create a multidimension array to output data for a monte carlo simulation and graph. So far, I can do a single array successfully. Input = [1,2,3,4,5] to shuffle [2,4,1,3,5] and desired output = [2,6,7,10,15] then graph in sheets or excel. With this algo, I have to brute force it over 1000 simulations. So I'm trying to have an input of [[1,2,3,4,5], 1000] to output a [5x1000] array of shuffled and cumulated simulations. If the first two shuffles are [2,4,1,3,5] and [5,3,1,2,4] then for output I'm seeking [[2,6,7,10,15][5,8,9,11,15]]. Here is code that works for a single output:

```
    function FYShuffle(array) {
      var m = array.length, i, t, total = 0;
      var sum = [];

      //parse array
      for (i=0;i<m;i++){
        array[i] = parseFloat(array[i]);
      }

      // While there remain elements to shuffle…
      while (m) {

        // Pick a remaining element…
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    
        // And swap it with the current element.
        t = array[m];
        array[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
      }  

    for (i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
            total = total + array[i];
            sum[i] = total;
        }

      return sum;
    }
```

Here is what I am trying, and currently not working, for a multidimensional array:

```
    function FYShuffleArray(array) {
      var sum = [];
      var sumArray = [];

      //parse array
      for (i=0;i<m;i++){
        array[i] = parseFloat(array[i]);
      }

      // create multidimensional array with shuffled cumulative returns
      // j for columns, i for rows
      for(j=0;j<2;j++){

        var m = array.length, i, t, total = 0;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle…
        while (m) {

          // Pick a remaining element…
          i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

          // And swap it with the current element.
          t = array[m];
          array[m] = array[i];
          array[i] = t;
        }  

        for (i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
              total = total + array[i];
              sum[i] = total;
          }

        //create multidimensional array;
        sumArray[j]=sum;
      }

      return sumArray;
    }
```

Any help or elegance greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `array[i] = parseFloat(array[i])` - if array[i] is an array, this isn't going to work.

Comment: Figured it out: function 

  // create multidimensional array
  for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
     sums[i] = [];
  }